What is the finite group $(\operatorname {PCO}^{\circ}_{2n})^{+}(q)$
In Table 22.1 on Page 193 of Malle & Testerman's book "Linear algebraic groups and finite groups of Lie type", the fixed point subgroup $G^F$ (where $F$ is a Steinberg endomorphism) of the adjoint algebraic group of type "$D_n$" is $(\operatorname {PCO}^{\circ}_{2n})^{+}(q)$.
How do I realize this group $(\operatorname {PCO}^{\circ}_{2n})^{+}(q)$ in Magma? Is it $\operatorname {PCSO}^+$, the projective conformal special orthogonal group?
Thank you.
Edit: Only odd $q$ is considered here.

I think this is right, at least if $p$ is odd, though I'm not familiar with Magma. I believe $\mathrm{PCO}{2n}^\circ$ is more or the less the same thing as $\mathrm{PSO}{2n}$, though people who know more than me don't like to write the latter thing for some reason. So $(\mathrm{PCO}_{2n}^\circ)^+(q)$ is probably just $\mathrm{PSO}^+(2n, q)$ in Magma.

In characteristic 2 there is a further wrinkle to do with the fact that determinant is trivial in characteristic 2, but still $[\mathrm{CO}{2n} : \mathrm{CO}{2n}^\circ] = 2$. Use "pseudodeterminant" instead, and conventions vary about what $\mathrm{SO}$ means in char 2. I don't know what Magma believes, but maybe you can check by computing the order of $\mathrm{PSO}^+_8(2)$.

@SeanEberhard If you type PCSOPlus(6,3) in Magma, you get a group which has a simple subgroup of index two, which is isomorphic to what Magma calls PSOPlus(6,3). I'm presuming that the extra two on top is a diagonal automorphism. Is this consistent with what you're saying? I'm not sure. It's easy to get confused about finite orthogonal groups.

So sorry. I forgot to mention that $q$ is odd.

@DaveBenson I must be wrong then. As far as I understood CSO means scalars x SO, so PCSO would be the same thing as PSO.

Updated guess: CO is the group of similarities of the orthogonal form, i.e., elements that map the orthogonal form to a scalar multiple of itself. When $k$ is algebraically closed that is the same thing as scalars times O, but once you take $F$-fixed points it's not quite, but scalars times O is an index-two subgroup (for $q$ odd). Probably $\mathrm{CO}^\circ$ for Malle--Testerman corresponds to CSO for Magma. In which case, yes, $(\mathrm{PCO}^\circ_{2n})^+(q) = \mathtt{PCSOPLus}(2n, q)$.

Concretely, if $M$ is the Gram matrix of the symmetric bilinear form, the conformal orthogonal group is the group of matrices $g$ such that $g^T M g = \lambda M$ for some nonzero $\lambda \in K = \mathbf{F}_q$, and this defines a natural homomorphism $c : \mathrm{CO}(M) \to K^\times$, $g \mapsto \lambda$. Note that $\det(g)^2 = c(g)^{2n}$, so $\det(g) = \pm c(g)^n$, and $\mathrm{CSO}(M) = {g \in \mathrm{CO}(M) : \det(g) = c(g)^n}$.

@SeanEberhard, some people don't like the PS notation because, depending on what you mean by it, either the map from the corresponding S group isn't surjective, or the PS group looks like an algebraic group but isn't. Similarly C = S times scalars is only guaranteed true over an algebraically closed field, not in general (analogous to GL vs. SL).

Malle-Testerman defines on page 35 that $PCO_{2n} = CO_{2n} / Z(CO_{2n})$, where $CO_{2n}$ is the conformal orthogonal group in dimension $2n$. Moreover they define $PCO_{2n}^\circ = CO_{2n}^\circ / Z(CO_{2n}^\circ)$, where $CO_{2n}^\circ$ is the connected component of $CO_{2n}$.
